# WebRequest using c# (VS2008) is perfectly working but not on Java (Ecplise)

Tags: java, timeout, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to read data from a webpage, and I have to do it using Java.
When I try to do it in Eclipse using Java i'm getting time out error:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
(Using HttpURLConnection):

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/"); 
URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection(); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

In order to understand where is the problem I tried doing the same task using c# and VS2008, and it worked perfectly fine, no time out at all.

I'm doing this from work so there's a firewall but I don't have information about it.

What can be the reason for this?

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: 1. Java is not an acronym.  2. You need to post some source code, and provide other relevant information (any firewall, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code:
                URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
                URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                        yc.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

```
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
```

found from here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

I'm doing this from work so there's a firewall but I don't have information about it.

Comment: URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
          URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                  new InputStreamReader(
                                  yc.getInputStream()));
          String inputLine;

          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
              System.out.println(inputLine);
          in.close();

The full code, sorry about that